# Prove that if $A^2x=x$ then $Ax=x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I feel this should be easy but I cant solve this problem:

Prove that if $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $x$ a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ both with real positive entries and $A^2x=x$ then $Ax=x$. I looking at the terms of the sum that defines the product $AAx$ and comparing with the entries of $x$ but I get nowhere. Can you give me any hints?

Comment: How much matrix theory do you know? What do you know about positive matrices? Does Perron Frobenius sound familiar?

Comment: Sorry, it does not. Last thing I saw in class was Jordan form and Spectral decomposition, but I can't remember anything specific to positive matrices.

Comment: Does $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ not count because $0$ is not positive?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, this problem requires (strictly) positive entries. Your matrix is an example of why it doesn't work for non-negative entries. Perron Frobenius deals with this nicely, and I can't seem to explain the problem without deriving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Perron Frobenius, since $A^2$ is a matrix with positive entries, it has a unique eigenvector with positive coefficients, and a positive eigenvalue. Likewise, $A$ is a matrix with positive entries, hence has a unique eigenvector with positive coefficients. Let this vector be $v$, and the eigenvalue be $\lambda > 0$. Then,

$$A^2 v = A (\lambda v ) = \lambda^2 v$$

which shows that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^2$ and $\lambda = 1$ (positive root). Hence, $v$ and $x$ are the same eigenvector, which means that $v$ is a (positive) multiple of $x$. Thus, $Ax=x$.

Comment: @user55414 Your comment came in 15 mins after mine, hence I posted my solution first. Will think about how to approach this without Perron Frobenius, but I think it's quite unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading about the theorem right now.

Comment: Any book recomendation to learn more about this? I'm using Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze

Comment: If I'm not wrong what the Perron-Frobenius theorem asserts is that for a positive matrix there existes  a unique *largest real* eigenvalue with corresponding strictly positive eigenvector , not that there exists only one eigenvalue and one positive eigenvector for it...

Comment: @DonAntonio From Wikipedia "There are no other positive (moreover non-negative) eigenvectors except positive multiples of v (respectively, left eigenvectors except w), i.e., all other eigenvectors must have at least one negative or non-real component." This uniqueness could follow by thinking of it as a strict contraction mapping.

Comment: @CalvinLin What if $x$ is a positive multiple of $v$?

Comment: @CarlosBeris Yes, the sentence should have said "Hence $v$ is a positive multiple of $x$.

Comment: @CalvinLin But why can we conclude $\lambda = 1$? I'm confused because $\lambda$ is supposed to be the greatest positive eigenvalue of $A^2$, so that would mean that $\lambda > 1$ because $1$ is the eigenvalue of $A^2$ associated to $x$. We won't have that if $v$ and $x$ are the same eigenvector but I don't know how to conclude that $\lambda=1$.

Comment: @CarlosBeris Perron Frobenius (which is quite a powerful theorem) states that we have a unique positive eigenvalue, and a unique corresponding all-positive eigenvector. Since we already know that $Ax=x$, this means that the eigenvalue is 1, and that $x \parallel v$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven easily without using Perron-Frobenius theorem. By assumption, both $x$ and $Ax$ are eigenvectors of $A^2$ for the eigenvalue $1$. Without loss of generality, suppose $c=\frac{(Ax)_n}{x_n}\le\frac{(Ax)_j}{x_j}$ for every $j$. Then $z=Ax-cx$ is a nonnegative vector whose last entry is zero. Yet, $A^2$ is positive and $A^2z=z$. In order that the last entry of $A^2z$ is zero, $z$ must be the zero vector. Therefore $Ax=cx$ and $x=A^2x=c^2x$. Hence $c=1$ and $Ax=x$.